# Switching out the Ember.js application template

Tags: ember.js

This is quite possibly a stupid question given my lack of experience with Ember JS at the moment.  However I was wondering how one would approach an application that may have  a few fundamentally different structural layouts.  From what I do understand the application template is designed to display elements that will always be there.

Consider the following:

- Login screen

  - No Header
  - No Sidebar
  - No Footer
  - Has Login box
- Main Application

  - Has Header
  - Has Sidebar
  - Has Footer
- Drawing part of the application

  - No Header
  - Has Canvas
  - Has Inspector
  - .. Etc

The question becomes how can one adjust the main application layout to cater to fundamental structural differences in an application.  I'm assuming that one could leave the application template blank and render these static bits in where needed, but I think that opens yourself to repeating configurations.  IE one wouldn't want to have to specify a layout for each possible route, or maybe you would?

Just looking for some pointers / best practice.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Totally opinion based here, but I think this is a perfect case for a blank application and different routes which are displayed completely differently.

```
App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('login');
  this.resource('home');
  this.resource('drawing');
  ..... etc
});
```

And then you can share/reuse templates super easy, so maybe in the home template you'd have something like

```
{{render 'header'}}
 other content
{{render 'footer'}}
```

then in your drawing template you'd have something like this

```
drawing stuff
{{render 'footer'}}
```

or whatever makes sense for your application.

Comment: +1 I make use of `{{partial}}` unless I need to pass in some specific model that differs from the current route, but this is pretty much how I've gone about my most recent Ember apps. I use a path observer in the application controller, too, which allows for some pretty powerful css bindings.